# How can I find all first child of a specific element of each div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the flowing HTML

```
<div class="group">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <ul>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <ul>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to find all the first `<li>` of each div. How can I achieve that with jQuery

so it should return a, c, and e

Comment: 5 answers already? Damn I'm too slow :(

Comment: ..but only two correct answers. :)

Comment: His malformed markup isn't helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 5 answers already, I know I'm late, but I read your question as wanting them returned as an array... so, if you're looking for an array, this is what you want:

```
var firstc = []

$(".group li:first-child").each(function() {
    firstc.push($(this).text());
});

alert(firstc);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kbGcE/

Comment: what does it return without the each?

Comment: `each` is used to cycle through the LIs and push the text of the LI into the array. So, without `each`, nothing is returned in my example. Why do you ask? What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Well...

```
$('.group').find('li:first-child')
```

Or even this

```
$('.group li:first-child');
```

Not as quick as the first one tho.

Answer (score 1):

```
selector = '.group > ul > li:first-child'
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AerQE/

Comment: This only gets you the first `.group > ul > li` in the entire DOM and not each one.

Comment: @BoltClock oops, thanks. I left off the `-child` accidentally. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [first-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) pseudo class to get the first child, once you have a selector to get the elements:

```
$.each($(".group > ul >li:first-child"), function () 
       {
           console.log($(this).text());
       });
```

See this sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3pqDZ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.group ul li:first-child')
```